# Can't start Jetbrains Hub & Youtrack at the same time

Tags: nginx, jetbrains-ide, youtrack, jetbrains-hub

I wanted to install Jetbrains Hub & Youtrack on my host. I've downloaded .zip files and extracted them to `/opt`.

I've configured them in the following way:

`bin/hub.sh configure --listen-port 3334 --base-url http://hub.example.com`

`bin/youtrack.sh configure --listen-port 3333 --base-url http://youtrack.example.com`

So I though youtrack would start at 3333 port and hub at 3334.
I've disabled SELinux (which previously caused some problems) and created Nginx rules.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name youtrack.example.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/youtrack.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3333;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hub.example.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/hub.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3334;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that I can start youtrack and access it from outside, as far as hub is not running and vice versa. But if both of them run, they restart each other. But I don't really understand, they shouldn't block each other should they? Do you have any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what does ```listen 80;``` do? is it saying "listen on port 80"?

Comment: Hello Ján,

Thank you for details.

What exactly happens when both YouTrack and Hub are running at the same time? Is one inaccessible or just stuck?

As a side note, not sure if it helps, but still, could you please try to move 

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;

ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

to "server {}" blocks ?

Is it possible to send us %hub_userhome%/logs and %youtrack_userhome%/logs folders? You can send them to youtrack-feedback@jetbrains.com

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run YouTrack and Hub on the same server.  I think the problem may be in the syntax of your configure command.  I believe the equal sign is missing and it should be:

```
bin /hub.sh configure --listen-port=3334 --base-url=http://hub.example.com

bin /youtrack.sh configure --listen-port=3333 --base-url=http://youtrack.example.com
```